# Install python library on non-default python version

Tags: rhel, python, odbc

The system (RHEL 6.5) already have python installed in `/usr/bin/python` 
I installed another version(3.3) in another directory `/data/tools/python3`, as I do not have root permission.

Now, I have 2 problem.

1. How can I call python 3.3 seperately ?
2. How to add module (pypyodbc) to python3.3 ? 
   I intent to use she-bang for calling scripts in 3.3

Comment: When you say `/data/tools/python3`, do you mean the `python3` binary or the base directory i.e. do you have something like `/data/tools/python3/bin/python3`, `/data/tools/python3/lib/...`, etc.?

Comment: Yes. I do have bin,lib directories in /data/tools/python3

Answer (score 1):

1. You can call python 3 using `/data/tools/python3` instead of `python`.
2. You will probably need to install it to a separate directory and then import the module from that path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines at the end of your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/data/tools/python3/bin
export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/tools/python3/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then logout and login again for the new variables to be loaded correctly.

After that, you can run Python3 with `python3` command.

To install `pypyodbc`, you can run `pip3 install pypyodbc` if you have installed pip on Python3. Otherwise, you can download the source for `pypyodbc` and run `python3 setup.py install`